Connecting local Spark cluster to GCS/ BQ
I need to connect a local Spark (2.4.4) cluster to GCP but without using the key.json file. I was exploring the options listed here https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcs/CONFIGURATION.md.
The one I am currently trying to get to work is ACCESS_TOKEN_PROVIDER.
I have written a custom AccessTokenProvider but couldn't get it to work! I was wondering if anyone managed to do that? if so, how please.
